# Delete the indexes of elements which exists more than once in an array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5600
    [1] => 5600
    [2] => 5500
    [3] => 5500
    [4] => 5003
    [5] => 5002
    [6] => 5001
    [7] => 768
    [8] => 768
    [9] => 767
    [10] => 730
    [11] => 666
    [12] => 575
)
```

Now I want to delete the indexes of elements  which exists more than once in an array. For example I want the above given array like this.

```
Array
(

    [0] => 5003
    [1] => 5002
    [2] => 5001
    [3] => 767
    [4] => 730
    [5] => 666
    [6] => 575
)
```

Share your ideas if any one has the key.

Comment: Use `array_unique`

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate repeating values with `array_unique`, restore indexes with `array_values`:

```
print_r(array_values(array_unique($arr)));
```

**Update**:

```
$new = [];
foreach (array_count_values($arr) as $k => $v) {
     if ($v == 1) {
         $new[] = $k;
     }
}
```

As a oneliner with `array_filter` (since php5.6):

```
$new = array_filter(
    array_count_values($arr), function($v, $k) {
        return $v == 1;
    },
     ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

Comment: First Thank you for sharing your idea,dear it gives again 5600,5500 & 768.Mean these are exists more than once,so should be deleted/removed.

Comment: Added update with `array_count_values`, which gives you frequency of elements in array. If frequency is `1` - you need this item.

Comment: Dear @u_mulder Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// sample input
$arr = array(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5);

// input
print_r($arr);

// to retain keys 
print_r( 
    array_diff($arr, array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)))
);

// to reset keys using array_values
print_r( 
array_values(
    array_diff($arr, array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)))
)
);

?>
```

Test results

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
 Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 5
)
Array
(
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question. Mine is not a nice solution. I used your question to make a little exercise of test driven development.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class RemoveNonUniqueItemsTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testEmptyArrayReturnEmptyArray()
    {
        $uniqueItems = Remover::keepOnlyUnique([]);
        $this->assertEquals(
            [],
            $uniqueItems->asArray()
        );
    }

    public function testArrayWithUniqueKeysReturnSameArray()
    {
        $uniqueItems = Remover::keepOnlyUnique([1,2,3]);
        $this->assertEquals(
            [1,2,3],
            $uniqueItems->asArray()
        );
    }

    public function testCountNumnerOfItemsAValueAppears()
    {
        $uniqueItems = Remover::keepOnlyUnique([1,2,3,3]);
        $this->assertEquals(
            2,
            $uniqueItems->items(3)
        );
    }

    public function testRemoveValuesThatExistsTwice()
    {
        $uniqueItems = Remover::keepOnlyUnique([1,2,3,3]);
        $this->assertEquals(
            [1,2],
            $uniqueItems->asArray()
        );
    }
}

final class Remover
{
    private $items;

    private function __construct(array $items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public static function keepOnlyUnique(array $items) : Remover
    {
        return new self($items);
    }

    public function asArray() : array
    {
        $newArray = [];
        foreach ($this->items as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
            if ($this->items($itemValue) == 1) {
                $newArray[] = $itemValue;
            }
        }
        return $newArray;
    }

    public function items(int $value) : int
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($this->items as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
            if ($itemValue == $value) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple loops.
Count how many times each value occurs. And then loop through these frequencies. If the value only occurs once add to our desired array.

```
<?php
function only_unique(array $values) {
    $result = $freq = array();
    foreach($values as $value)
        isset($freq[$value]) ? $freq[$value]++ : $freq[$value] = 1; 
    foreach($freq as $key => $value)
        if($value == 1)
            $result[] = $key;

    return $result;
}

$nums = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4];
var_dump(only_unique($nums));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
}
```

The above is similar to below:

```
$desired =
    array_keys(
        array_filter(
            array_count_values($nums), function($v) {
                return $v == 1;
            }
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every Answer offered here is right.... but then, again... *here's another one:*

```
 <?php
    $arr    = [
        5600, 5600, 5500, 5500, 5003, 5002,
        5001, 768,  768,  767,  730,  666,   575,
    ];

    function arraySansDuplicates($array){
        $result             = [];
        foreach($array as $value){
            if(!in_array($value, $result)){
                $result[]   = $value;
            }else{
                $key        = array_search($value, $result);
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
        return array_values($result);
    }

    var_dump( arraySansDuplicates($arr) );
```